# icons shown in left margin of IDE during debugging

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-2012

During debugging, I see these two symbols (shown in green rectangles). Can someone help me understand what does these indicate?

[image]

Comment: This is the Thread icon. Does that make sense in this context?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is used to represent the presence of threads at the current statement of the debugger. It allows you to determine which thread is active for the debugger.

For example, when my cursor is on the line `Thread.Sleep(10)` in this pointless example, I can choose which worker thread I am interested in (and set breakpoints by its process ID):

[image: Thread example]

Here I can see each of the worker threads that are currently active, and that I am currently stepping through the worker thread with the ID 28468. I can also flag threads easily or try to move the cursor to a different thread where possible.

Note that you will only see the thread icons if you've enabled "Show Threads in Source" on the debugger toolbar.

[image: Show Threads in Source]